Preserving Invertibility When Adding Rows
Suppose I have two $m\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that an $m\times m$ submatrix of $A$ is invertible if and only if the corresponding $m \times m$ submatrix of $B$ is. Now let's say I append a row at the bottom of $A$, and we can denote this new $(m+1)\times n$ matrix as $A_2$. Can I always find a row to append onto the bottom of $B$ such that an $(m+1)\times (m+1)$ submatrix of $A_2$ is invertible if and only if the corresponding $(m+1)\times (m+1)$ submatrix of $B_2$ is? $B_2$ is the new matrix obtained from adding a row onto $B$.
I suspect this is dependent upon which field the matrices have entries in, but I've made no luck in this problem so far. I've tried thinking about it by trying to compute determinants via Laplace expansions or using determinant formulas for block matrices, but that hasn't helped.

Have you tried to disprove it yet? That is, tried to find a counter-example? Alternating between trying to prove and trying to disprove is often a good way to make progress. You use what you learn from failed attempts in one direction to guide you in attempts in the other direction.
